# How to make realtime list updates Firebase in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

How to create real-time list (UI) updates in Flutter using Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has a database called `Firestore database`. And it's a real-time database. That means you can listen to those changes in real time. But before that, you will need to configure some things for it.

1. Create a project on firebase and bind it with your flutter project.
2. Enable firestore database and modify the permission according to your need.
3. Add packages in your flutter project for firebase like `cloud_firestore`  to get the functions for listening to the data in real-time.
4. You can use `StreamBuilder` or `FutureBuilder` for listening to the data.

You can follow this [guide](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/using-firebase-firestore-in-flutter-b0ea2c62bc7#:%7E:text=How%20to%20integrate%20firebase%20with,click%20on%20the%20android%20icon.). It has all the necessary steps according to your needs.

Comment: I used FutureBuilder, but the list is not updated.

Comment: The list will not be updated in FutureBuilder in real time, for that you have to use StreamBuilder, But if you want to get the list only once, then you can use FutureBuilder, I hope it solves your query.